How to pass a c variable into the linker file?
Lets say I have,
#define SW_VERSION_ADDRESS  0x08005FE0
#define SW_REVISION  "123"
const u32 sw_version_address =  SW_VERSION_ADDRESS;
const char gv_SW_revision[18] __attribute__((section(".sw_version"))) = SW_REVISION;

and in my linker file
 .sw_version sw_version_address : 
  {
    *(.sw_version)          
  } 

I think the problem is that I am not passing the sw_version_address from the c file to my linker correctly.
I have tried to replce the variable sw_version_address in my linker file with hardcoded address and then it works. However I dont want to hardcode it in the linker file.
Any suggestions?

What is the problem that you see? Your code looks fine, or close to fine

Also it depends on where you expect it to be seen. In the physical binary file, or in the RAM where this binary is being loaded fully or partially? You need to describe more about your application.

@EugeneSh. it looks totaly wrong to me

@0___________ I do not agree. It is an initialized const, which would go into .rodata by default, but in the code it goes into a custom section.

@EugeneSh. you do not understand I think - he wants to use the value stored in the C variable to define the address of the section in the linker script. Linker does not read any variables from object files

@0___________ Oh.. if that's the case, then I indeed misunderstood the question

OP, you know, you can #include stuff in your linker script and then pass it through cpp for preprocessing. Just make sure the included fine does not contain any syntax the linker won't like. Or use some other way to autogenerate the script.

Some linkers let you go the other way around though: define address constants in the linker script which you can later re-use in the C code.

You can't use a variable as the value in your linker script.
There is no workaround.
To archive it you need to dynamically generate your .h file and definitions for the linker script.
You can also as @Eugene Sh suggested preprocess the file with C definitions into the linker script:
"def.h":
#define SW_VERSION_ADDRESS  0x08005FE0

"script.ld.in":
#include "def.h"

 .sw_version SW_VERSION_ADDRESS : 
  {
    *(.sw_version)          
  } 

And add the build step:
cpp -P script.ld.in -o script.ld

